# SSRS 2014 : Add several cells inside of a large cell

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have created a table like below. The table use a dataset  [image]

I want to add several cells within one of the row like below and be able to query through the same dataset and most of all, be able to leave the other rows intact (see below).

[image]

Issue is I cannot do it within the table.

One of my workaround solutions, which is not satisfying to me , is to to create a rectangle then add another table / matrix within that rectangle (like I did in the image above). Then superimpose the rectangle in one of the cell of the table / matrix I want to split.  However, when I'm deploying the report, I have an error `tablix ‘Tablix15’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members`

The other solution is to create several columns then merge the cells of the rows I don't need and keep the cells I want. Drawback : Very tedious and lacking of flexibility

If you have any ideas on how to do it or fix the error above, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satisfying or not - the solution is to create a rectangle in the cell and add tablixes to this rectangle for the extra columns.

You are getting the `detail member with inner members` error as I imagine you are probably nesting Row Groupings.

Consider this example, showing a nested table.

[image]

When run like this I get the following error, exactly as you do above

> The tablix ‘Tablix8’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members.

This `static inner members` it refers to is saying that it isn't going to allow you to do more grouping at this lower level.  This should be fine though based on the information you presented in the question, as you only want the values for this specific Row.  Therefore, to remove the grouping, right click the Row Header, select Row Group -> Delete Group and then select Delete Group Only.

[image]

Note the (three lined) `=` symbol has disappeared from the Row header.  When this report is then set to Preview, it now renders as expected

[image]

Hopefully this will solve your issue.  Please let me know if you have further problems or queries on this.

Comment: Last night @jonnus saved my life from a report issue (with that soundtrack https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtfZbj4J71A). Many thanks ;)